# iOS - UILabel on top of UITextView border

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am trying to achieve something like this with a UITextView

[image]

This is what I have come with so far

```
func createTextFieldOutline() {
        textViewBorder = CAShapeLayer()
        let bez = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius: 7)
        textViewBorder?.path = bez.cgPath
        /* some styling code */
        if let outline = textViewBorder {
            self.layer.addSublayer(outline)
            self.createFloatingLabel()
        }
    }
    
    func createFloatingLabel() {
        let titleLabel = UILabel()
        /* some styling code */
        titleLabel.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        titleLabel.sizeToFit()
        titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        titleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: -7.5, width: 32, height: 15)
        titleLabel.text = "Test"
        self.layer.insertSublayer(titleLabel.layer, above: textViewBorder)
    }
```

The way I use these methods is I have created a subclass of UITextView and call above two methods in `convenience init`. But it does not put the label on top of border. It puts it behind the border like this:

[image]

The same approach works for `UITextField` but not for `UITextView`. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: it looks like the top label is being clipped to the bounds of the text view, have you tried messing with clips to bounds?

Comment: @Tadreik yes to no avail

Comment: Any special reason you need to add the border and label to that view, as opposed to just encapsulating them in a new view? That would solve the clipping issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I have founded best pod for implement this kind of TextField.

`pod 'MaterialComponents/TextControls+OutlinedTextFields'`

https://material.io/components/text-fields/ios#outlined-text-field

You can find more UI which looks like android UI on this platform.

https://material.io/

```
let estimatedFrame = ...
let textArea = MDCOutlinedTextArea(frame: estimatedFrame)
textArea.label.text = "Label"
textArea.leadingAssistiveLabel.text = "This is helper text"
textArea.textView.text = "This is an outlined text area with enough text to span two lines."
textArea.sizeToFit()
view.addSubview(textArea)
```

[image]